# Merge videos diagonally in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, shell

I am trying to diagonally merge two frames using ffmpeg. [ffmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend-1) has an example for diagonal split: `blend=all_expr='if(gt(X,Y*(W/H)),A,B)'`. This split, however, results in split from top left to bottom right. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35352120/11664800) in stackoverflow shows an example of that, and also a similar command that achieves it, using a similar command to previous.

I want a diagonal split from bottom left to top right, but I can't figure out the correct ffmpeg command to achieve that. How do I modify the command to achieve the result I'm after?

Comment: `blend=all_expr='if(gt(X,W-Y*(W/H)),A,B)'`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by first horizontally flipping both the input videos, and then combining them. Horizontally flipping the combined video results in a video where the inputs are combined diagonally from bottom left to top right:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]hflip[v1];[0:v]hflip[v2];
[v1][v2]blend=all_expr='if(gt(X,Y*(W/H)),A,B)',hflip" \
out.mp4
```